# How to make a larger "\dot"

Tags: math-mode, symbols, presentations, accents

I'm writing up some notes that will be displayed on an overhead projector. The standard time-derivative `\dot{x}` produces a dot that is hard to see. Does anyone know of a package or have a macro that produces a (nice looking) larger dot? Similarly with `\ddot{x}`.

At the moment, I've been supplied with some ugly code that produces an ugly output:

```
\def\dt#1{{\buildrel  {\hbox{\LARGE . }} \over {#1}}}    % dot-over 
\def\ddt#1{{\buildrel {\hbox{\LARGE ..}} \over {#1}}}    % double dot
```

Comment: Related Question: [Making a thicker \cdot for dot product (that is thinner than \bullet)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235118/making-a-thicker-cdot-for-dot-product-that-is-thinner-than-bullet).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use the `accents` package and its command `\accentset` to create faked accents. Here`s an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand*{\dt}[1]{%
  \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .}}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\ddt}[1]{%
  \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .\hspace{-0.25ex}.}}{#1}}
\begin{document}
$\dot{x} \neq \dt{x}$

$\ddot{x} \neq \ddt{x}$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Instead of a large bold period you could also choose for instance a tiny \bullet.

Answer (score 14):

The `amsmath` package provides the commands `\overset` and `\underset` to set arbitrary things over/under other arbitrary things. So with `amsmath` and `bm` loaded you can use

```
\overset{\bm .}{a}
```

to obtain an "a" with a bold dot on it.

Comment: For a closer dot, with horizontal positioning appropriate to italic characters, you could try `\renewcommand{\dot}[1] {\overset{\,_{\mbox{\Large .}}}{#1}}` , where `\Large` may be replaced by another size or `\bf`, to taste. The effect is easily seen by commenting the `\renewcommand` in and out.

Comment: Alternatively, create a `\bigdot` command with: `\newcommand{\bigdot}[1]{\overset{\bm .}{#1}}`

Answer (score 3):

The normal `\dot` uses the dot accent from the font, so switching font families to a font set with larger accents would be the cleanest solution.

Comment: Can you give an example? Would that also switch the font of the text/math?

Comment: No, sorry. I do not use LaTeX myself. Anyway, I think Caramdir's answer is better

Comment: For slides, a sans-serif font might be a good idea, and it *may* help with the dot problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe rather use `\partial_t x` or `x_t`? Also quite compact and much more noticeable.

Comment: I agree, but I'm writing the notes for someone else, so I don't get a say in the matter.