# Bold italic vectors

Tags: math-mode, bold, vector, italic

I am trying to display vectors as bold *and* italic. The command `\mathbf` sets the letters non-italic. I also googled a bit and stumbled upon `\mathbf{\em y}` or `\mathbfit{y}`, which all didn't work.

I hope someone can help me on this.

Comment: I've marked your inline code with backticks `\``. (You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.)

Comment: Your command `\mathbf` is quite good at least for the unit vectors `\mathbf{i}`, `\mathbf{j}` and `\mathbf{k}`.

Comment: Related question: [fonts - How can I get bold math symbols? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols/596#596) (most answers there are italic as well.)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It depends on the math font, but the `bm` package can handle most of them. The usage is then `$\bm{y}$`

Comment: This works. But it is not working within multicolumn environment like the following case,

\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\bm{a\:(\si{\angstrom})}$}

but it works for

\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\bm{\alpha_T\;  (K^{-1})}$}. 

How to solve this?

Answer (score 56):

There is also `\boldsymbol{}` from the package [`amsbsy`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsbsy) (loaded by [`amsmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)). See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/bm-package-versus-boldsymbol) for a discussion of the advantages and disadvantages of each command.

Comment: Cool answer. In my case no need to load extra packages (like `bm`), because when working with math stuff, I usually use the `amsmath`. :)

Answer (score 34):

What I did, is to declare my own command for a vector, well its pretty basic, but you can add other features, like an arrow.

```
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
```

And the usage:

```
\vect{X} = \left[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n \right]^T
```

returning:

[image]

Comment: This is already covered by [another answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132912/5764)...

Comment: Yes, I took the idea from http://kawahara.ca/latex-bold-vector-and-arrow-vectors/. Sorry I didn't point that out.

Comment: You can also allow the usage within normal text by
    \newcommand{\vect}[1]{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{#1}}}

Answer (score 17):

The answer depends on the math fonts you are actually using. For the standard fonts and as long as you use only letters and numbers this should work:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathbfit}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}

\begin{document}
$a=\mathbfit{a}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

A few years late to the game, but since people are still linking to this question, here’s an update.

The `\mathbfit` command is defined in both `unicode-math` and the legacy `isomath` package.  In either case, it will match the current font, or the package allows you to load a different bold italic math alphabet.

There is also a semantic `\vectorsym` command in `isomath`, which sets letters in bold italic but digits in bold upright.

In `unicode-math`, you would want to use `\symbfit` for bold italic math symbols (as `\mathbfit` matches the text font, not the math font). There are no bold italic mathematical digits in Unicode, so you would need to use `\symbfup` for digits instead.

Answer (score 9):

A good choice is to use the `physics` package, which provides the `\vb*{}` command to do what you are looking for, as well as other commands to display vectors:

[image]

Code:

```
\vb{v} \quad \vb*{v} \quad \va{v} \quad \va*{v}
```

(with `\usepackage{physics}`)

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for, bold-lower, non-italics x for vector of features.