# How to write letters in bold in the math mode?

Tags: math-mode, bold

In mathematics, a letter, say, g, can stand for a scalar, while a letter in bold, e.g., **g** stands for a vector.

Here is my question:

How can one turn the letter into bold in the math mode?

For example, how can I turn g here into bold?

```
$$-\nabla p+\mu\nabla^2u+g\delta(x-x_0)=0 $$
```

Comment: It is preferrable to use `\[` and `\]` as discussed [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to). Also see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/bold-math-symbols) for more on bold math symbols.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Using the `bm` package. The `\mathbf` command can only be used for non-italic symbols, instead the `amsmath` package defines the `\boldsymbol` command that can be used with every literal symbol or math operator. The `bm` package redefines the `\boldsymbol` command providing the `\bm` command and is independent from `amsmath`. So you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\[ \boldsymbol{g} \qquad \bm{g} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: For non-italics, it is
`\mathrm{\mathbf{j}}`

Answer (score 62):

Use `\mathbf{g}` for bold in math mode.

Comment: `\mathbf` doesn't work for everything

Comment: @pratnala That's true, but that also wasn't what the question was asking. See [the accepted answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22661/80) for a more general solution.

Comment: I think mathbf will turn italic letters into normal letters

Comment: As the accepted answer and also this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14400/192743 suggests, if you need bold italic, use `\bm`.

Answer (score 3):

An update: if you use `unicode-math`, it provides `\symbfup` and `\symbfit` commands for bold upright and italic letters, respectively.  There are similar bold sans-serif, calligraphic and script alphabets.  There are also `\mathbfup` and `\mathbfit` commands, intended for whole words in math mode, but I’ve honestly never had cause to use them.  Finally, traditional math commands are supported for backward-compatibility.

The `\boldsymbol` command still works, including for symbols other than letters, if you load one of the math fonts that comes in bold (such as XITS Math) or if you declare a bold math font with `\setmathfont[version=bold]`.  This can be a `FakeBold` version of the math font, for instance,

```
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}[
   version=bold,
   FakeBold = 1.2 ]
```

It can also be useful to add `\bfseries\boldmath` to your header formatting, to make your math match the weight of the text.

The one disadvantage of this is that, as of 2021, you cannot use `version=` and `range=` together.  Your bold symbol font will only work if you do not mix-and-match different math fonts with `range=`.

If you stick to legacy math fonts, `isomath` adds a bold italic `\mathbfit` alphabet, and optionally bold sans-serif math alphabets for tensors.  The `mathalpha` package adds bold versions of several other math alphabets, such as a heavy blackboard bold and a bold calligraphic.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `statmath` package, which defines a number of commands related to statistics, including bold-face versions of the Latin and Greek letters --- `\bfg`, `\bfbeta`, `\bfOmega` and so on. I've found this a very useful package if many of the symbols in your formulas should be bold to begin with: it really cuts down on typing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{statmath}
\begin{document}
$$-\nabla p + \mu\nabla^2 u + \bfg\delta(x - x_0) = 0$$
\end{document}
```

FWIW, the package uses `\mathbf` and `\boldsymbol` by default, but can be configured via a package option to use `bm`'s `\bm` command instead.