# Strange formatting issue when compiling

Tags: math-mode

When I write

```
${\cal{A}} = \textbf{y}_{i}, \forall i = 1,\cdots, n^{2}$,
```

I get:

[image]

However, if I remove the curly braces around `\cal{A}` and instead write

```
$\cal{A} = \textbf{y}_{i}, \forall i = 1,\cdots, n^{2}$,
```

then I get

[image]

I'm just really curious what's causing this interesting issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `\cal` is not intended for use in math mode. Instead of it rather use `\mathcal` and your problem will disappear.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22643/how-to-write-letters-in-bold-in-the-math-mode/

Comment: @Zarko - Please see the answer I just posted. `\cal` is a PlainTeX font switching command and, as such, is very much meant to be used in math mode. However, precisely because it's a PlainTeX holdover, it shouldn't be used in a LaTeX document written after 1994.

Answer (score 6):

You wrote,

> I'm just really curious what's causing this interesting issue

**Short answer**: To use `\cal` in any LaTeX document written after 1994 [!] is either an accident waiting to happen -- as is the case with your sample code -- or won't work at all -- say, if the `memoir` document class is used.

**Longer answer**: `\cal` is a plain-TeX font switching command that is implemented in some, but not all, LaTeX2e document classes, as a legacy command to ease the changeover from LaTeX209 to LaTeX2e. (That changeover occurred in 1994.) Because `\cal` is a *switch* rather than a command that takes an argument, its scope is *through to the end of the current TeX group*. Hence, by writing `\cal{A}`, one creates the false impression that only `A` is affected by whatever `\cal` does; that's not the case, as you've (re)discovered. One *must* encase `\cal A` in curly braces -- i.e., write `{\cal A}` -- in order to avoid creating a typographic disaster.  What you *really* ought to be doing, though, is to write `\mathcal{A}`. (In this regard, `\cal` is not different from the other legacy/PlainTeX font switching commands, such as `\bf`, `\it`, `\sl`, and `\sc`.)

Additional comment: Your sample code contains one further inaccuracy and one typographically questionable choice.

- To write `\textbf{y}` in math mode will sooner or later come back to haunt you, especially if the document's text and the math fonts don't look alike. You should be writing `\textbf{y}` in text mode and `\mathbf{y}` in math mode.
- To write `1,\cdots, n^{2}` is somewhat unconventional from a typographic point of view, to put it charitably. Better to write `1,\ldots, n^{2}` or, better still, `1,\dots, n^{2}` -- and let LaTeX decide whether to generate a typographic ellipsis that's placed on the baseline or on the mathline. (The mathline is where the mathematical `-` (minus) symbol is placed.) `\cdots` should be employed, say, to elide a sequence of binary operations, as in `\prod_{i=1}^N a_i = a_1 a_2 \cdots a_N`. In contrast, `\ldots` should be used to abbreviate a list of comma-separated items.

To summarize, then, do consider replacing

```
${\cal{A}} = \textbf{y}_{i}, \forall i = 1,\cdots, n^{2}$,
```

with

```
$\mathcal{A} = \mathbf{y}_{i} \quad \forall i = 1,\dots, n^{2}$,
```

Comment: +1 But allow me a small correction: `\dots` decides where to put the ellipsis only with `amsmath`. The kernel definition simply discrimitates between text and math mode but always puts them on the baseline.