# How to get bold times new roman in math

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I'm using `\usepackage{mathptmx}` to use times new roman font in math. But I can't make the font bold by using `\boldmath`, which works fine with default computer modern font.

I'm using `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}` to use times new roman for the whole document.

How to get bold times new roman font in math so that it blends well with other text?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863). Also, it would be great if you could add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mathptmx package is not the best way to load the times font as the fonts are both incomplete and a patchwork of symbols from different sources.

Among the free fonts, you best choice today is probably [newtx](http://ctan.org/pkg/newtx) (alternatively, on older distributions, you have [txfonts](http://ctan.org/pkg/txfonts), but they have some spacing problems):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

$y = f(x)$

$\mathbf{y=f(x)}$

{\boldmath$y=f(x)$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: and `newtxmath` is not a patchwork?

Comment: Does it change font of non-math text?  I'm using `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}` to set default font to times new roman.

Comment: @user21916: if you only want to change the math, then don't load `newtxtext`. But the text fonts are more complete than `ptm` (they have real small caps), so it's probably a good idea to load both packages.

Comment: I have a lot of tables, in the header row of every table there are many math stuff.  Is there a way to turn on math bold universally? something like \boldmath and \unboldmath

Comment: I found that \boldmath and \unboldmath work here.

Answer (score 4):

Use `\mathbf{..}` instead of `{\boldmath ..}`. The following minimal example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfit}{T1}{ptm}{b}{it}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
aaa\textbf{aaa}\textbf{\textit{aaa}}
$aaa \mathbf{aaa} \mathbfit{aaa}$
\end{document}
```

lists the output fonts as

```
Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(633.0+0.0)x407.0
.\glue 16.0
.\vbox(617.0+0.0)x345.0, shifted 62.0
..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 12.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
..\glue 25.0
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 539.77744fil
...\write-{}
...\glue(\topskip) 5.27003
...\hbox(4.72997+0.16492)x345.0, glue set 239.18018fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 a
....\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 a
....\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 a
....\kern 0.0
....\OT1/ptm/b/n/10 a
....\OT1/ptm/b/n/10 a
....\OT1/ptm/b/n/10 a
....\kern 0.0
....\OT1/ptm/b/it/10 a
....\OT1/ptm/b/it/10 a
....\OT1/ptm/b/it/10 a
....\kern 0.0
....\glue 2.5 plus 1.49998 minus 0.59998
....\mathon
....\OML/ztmcm/m/it/10 a
....\OML/ztmcm/m/it/10 a
....\OML/ztmcm/m/it/10 a
....\hbox(4.72997+0.13994)x15.0
.....\OT1/ptm/b/n/10 a
.....\OT1/ptm/b/n/10 a
.....\OT1/ptm/b/n/10 a
....\hbox(4.555+0.13495)x15.0
.....\T1/ptm/b/it/10 a
.....\T1/ptm/b/it/10 a
.....\T1/ptm/b/it/10 a
....\mathoff
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 23.18011
..\hbox(6.81989+0.0)x345.0, glue set 170.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 1
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

As a reference, see [Bold italic vectors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14395/5764).

Comment: running `pdffonts <file>.pdf` is a bit shorter ...

Comment: how to have italic bold when using both mathptmx and mathbf?

Comment: Is it possible to make \mathbfit the default for math env?

Comment: As in *all* math is `\mathbfit`? *Always*?

Comment: If mathptmx can be used for bold math, why \boldmath does not work?

Comment: Not always, I want to control when to start \mathbfit and when to stop it, just like \boldmath and \unboldmath

Comment: I found that your solution can only make a-z letters bold, other stuff like operators are not bold

Answer (score 4):

there are no free math fonts for Times in Type 1 format. However, use the new OpenType font `TeX Gyre Pagella Math`  with `xelatex` or `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont[bold-style=TeX]{TG Termes Math}
\begin{document}

Times are gonna change \ldots

$y=f(x)$
$\mathbf{y=f(x)}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the bold letters should also be in italic use

```
\setmathfont[bold-style=ISO]{TG Termes Math}
```

Comment: the [mathtime pro 2 lite](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html#MTPro2_Lite) fonts are (a) times-based, (b) pretty satisfactory for general user, and (c) free.  they're not on ctan (in principle they could be withdrawn at any time) but they seem a good bargain to me (i don't write maths any more...)

Comment: the lite version has no bold symbols

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I didn't manage to set up XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX in my Linux box

Comment: Can someone help me to get the NFSS name of "mathtime pro 2" upright bold font?