# How to make bold and italic symbol inside an equation?

Tags: math-mode, bold, italic

My problem is to make bold and italic symbol `\widehat{abc}`. 
According to Online LaTeX Equation Editor I should use `\boldsymbol`, but it seems not to work in TeXMaker. 
Also `\mathit{\mathbf{\widehat{x}}}` doesn't give expected result.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14395/bold-italic-vectors In short, add `\usepackage{bm}` and write `\bm{\widehat{abc}}`. (Also, the fact that you use Texmaker is actually irrelevant, it is just an editor, and the result doesn't depend on the editor.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! More information on this site can be seen in the faq and the Unofficial TeX-SX FAQ http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1144/19384 as well as the markdown help http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help. Welcome to the community!