# How to make italic and bold letter with \pmb command?

Tags: amsmath, italic, boldmath

I'd like to italicize the letter in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\pmb{\mathsf{z}}$
\end{document}
```

I've already read the discussion in this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14395/bold-italic-vectors), but it does not offer a solution for the `\pmb` command. Any help?

P.S. Since I've already used \boldsymbol, I would like to use a different notation style for the letter above.

Comment: Why you don't use `\mathit{}`? `\mathsf` is for serifless letters (in math mode)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the suggestion. The reason is that I want to differentiate two notation styles and \mathit{} has already been used.

Comment: Well, this is confusing: You already have `\mathit`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry, actually no, I didn't use \mathit. Instead I've already used boldsymbol{}. And now I want to use a different style for differentiation purpose.

Comment: You wrote that `\mathit` is already been used. Your question does not show the slightest indication that `sf` is wanted too! Slanted sf is not possible with every font

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry I misstated in my first comment above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Computer Modern fonts lack sans serif boldface slanted, but the Latin Modern fonts have it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{OT1}{lmss}{m}{sl}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfbfit}{OT1}{lmss}{bx}{sl}

\begin{document}
$\mathsfit{z}\ne\mathsfbfit{z}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

A slightly different solution that avoids wasting a math group (useful if you happen to use up them all):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{OT1}{lmss}{m}{sl}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{bold}{OT1}{lmss}{bx}{sl}

\begin{document}
$\mathsfit{z}\ne\bm{\mathsfit{z}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems very simple and straightforward. And it's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @bluepole I added a different solution in case you run out of math groups.

Answer (score 2):

For making Math appear Sans Serif, you can load `cmbright`, but this will make *all* math like that. You can see this question for switching between it and none: [Make mathfont respect the surrounding family](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33165/4778)

You can then use `\boldsymbol{}` for making it bold.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{z}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'd like to differentiate two notation styles, so cmbright would not work for me.

Comment: @bluepole You can differentiate. It's just gonna take some code. See the linked question.