# how to write "bold typeface" and "italics" in latex?

Tags: symbols

**Note:** I am using jupyter notebook (MathJax) rather than tex.

["Ian Goodfellow, Yoshua Bengio, Aaron Courville. Deep Learning"](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/) use italics typeface to denote Scalars, pointed out by red arrow in the following figure

[image]

bold typeface to denote Vectors, pointed out by blue arrow in the following figure

[image]

how to write these 2 types of linear algebra notations in latex?

I searched "bold" on the author's [github](https://github.com/goodfeli/dlbook_notation/search?q=bold&unscoped_q=bold) and got this

[image]

which is not helpful.

I tried this command

```
$x$ $\boldsymbol x$
```

which is even worse.

this command does better

```
$x \mathbf{x}$
```

although this is obviously using different font in the Deep Learning Book

[image]

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Bold italic vectors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14395/5764)

Comment: `\usepackage{bm}` ... `$\bm{x}$` ...