# Math bold italic symbols with mathspec

Tags: xetex, bold, mathspec

In `mathspec` the command `\mathbit`is not defined, I followed advice from [Ulrike here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14395/bold-italic-vectors) in order to define it, but it desperately remains in Computer Modern:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathbfit}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{NotoSans-Regular}[
    Extension      = .ttf,
    Ligatures      = TeX,
    BoldFont       = NotoSans-Bold,
    ItalicFont     = NotoSans-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = NotoSans-BoldItalic,
    Numbers        = Lining
]
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[
    Extension      = .ttf,
    Ligatures      = TeX,
    BoldFont       = NotoSans-Bold,
    ItalicFont     = NotoSans-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = NotoSans-BoldItalic,
    Numbers        = Lining
]{NotoSans-Regular}
\setmathrm[
    Extension      = .ttf,
    Ligatures      = TeX,
    BoldFont       = NotoSans-Bold,
    ItalicFont     = NotoSans-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = NotoSans-BoldItalic,
    Numbers        = Lining
]{NotoSans-Regular}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek},
    Extension      = .ttf,
    Ligatures      = TeX,
    Numbers        = Lining]{NotoSans-BoldItalic} 
\begin{document}
Blabla $x, \mathbf{x}, \mathbfit{x}, \mathrm{sin}(x)$
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

in other words, everything is in Noto Sans (not that I like Noto, but I use it to exemplify the problem with a widely available font) except for the `\mathbfit` part. How can I solve this issue?

(I read somewhere that I need to use the `unicode-math`. OK but, first, I have no intention to type math symbols in Unicode, and second, I get compatibility problems such as "amsmath package has to be loaded first" even though I didn't requested any `amsmath` package…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a math alphabet based on the main font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\setmainfont{NotoSans}[
    Extension      = .ttf,
    NFSSFamily     = NotoSans,
    Ligatures      = TeX,
    UprightFont    = *-Regular,
    BoldFont       = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
    Numbers        = Lining
]
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[
    Extension      = .ttf,
    Ligatures      = TeX,
    UprightFont    = *-Regular,
    BoldFont       = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
    Numbers        = Lining
]{NotoSans}
\setmathrm[
    Extension      = .ttf,
    Ligatures      = TeX,
    UprightFont    = *-Regular,
    BoldFont       = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
    Numbers        = Lining
]{NotoSans}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfit}{TU}{NotoSans}{b}{it}


\begin{document}
Blabla $x, \mathbf{x}, \mathbfit{x}, \mathrm{sin}(x)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The trick with `NFSSFamily` is great! Thank a lot! What is TU encoding?

Comment: @yannis It's the standard encoding used for Unicode fonts. When `mathspec` was written, it used to be EU1 (XeLaTeX) or EU2 (LuaLaTeX), but then a new encoding was defined.