# How can I make the crossed-"O" ($\oslash$) bold?

Tags: bold, characters

I'd like to bolden the crossed-o but

```
\textbf{$\oslash$}
```

does nothing!

Comment: `\usepackage{bm}` and `$\bm{\oslash}$` should do.

Comment: @mateuz Please, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols

Comment: Please note that `\oslash` is not the same as the HTML-entity `&oslash;` (a.k.a. the Danish/Norwegian [letter Ø](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98)), or the [diameter symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter#Diameter_symbol) ⌀, or the empty set symbol ∅.

Comment: `\textbd{$\oslash$}` will produce an "Undefined control sequence" error, so I guess you mean `\textbf{$\oslash$}`.

Comment: Kahen's comment is accurate. You shouldn't be using `\oslash` anyway, but rather just Ø, which you can do if you use UTF-8 as your file encoding. See the comments/answers to your other questions on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several options for obtaining bold characters in math mode. Using the `bm`-package with `\bm` is considered the [best practice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/bm-package-versus-boldsymbol) for that.

**Implementation**

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
Options for bold $\oslash$:
$\boldsymbol{\oslash}$ vs.
{\boldmath $\oslash$} vs.
$\bm{\oslash}$
\end{document}
```

**Output**

> [image: bm]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `bm` package to get bold math characters.  See

[How can I get bold math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/2693)

However, for your actual purposes, (linguistics) you should not be using the math symbol `\oslash` anyway, but you should just use the regular upper case Ø, in which case it can be made boldface without any extra packages.

Comment: But what package do I need to get "Ø"? Copy-and-pasting directly gives me Ã Ÿ

Comment: @mateuz You shouldn't need a package. How is your input file encoded? You should use `latin1` or `utf8` You need to load the `inputenc` package with the correct encoding specified (unless you're using XeTeX) You also need to make sure that you are loading a font that contains that the glyph (so `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (again, unless you are using XeTeX)). If you took my other advice, you should be using XeTeX in which case your file must be encoded utf8 and things should just work.

Comment: Not sure how it's encoded (I'm using TextMate 4, not XeTeX), but even with \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}, I still get those two glypsh I mentioned above.