# Combining Vogt's widebar with bm and mathcal

Tags: math-mode, symbols, accents

Hendrik Vogt provided [an excellent alternative to overline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/can-i-get-a-widebar-without-using-the-mathabx-package/60253#60253).

I am experiencing issues with using widebar in conjunction with bm and mathcal.

A [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186607/combine-boldsymbol-and-widebar) has been asked already. However, the resolution of merely switching to the bm package for the bold symbols does not work in this case, as the following example demonstrates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\makeatletter
\let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent
\newcommand*\if@single[3]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%
  \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}%
  \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
  }
%The bar will be moved to the right by a half of \macc@kerna, which is computed by amsmath:
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
%If there's a superscript following the bar, then no negative kern may follow the bar;
%an additional {} makes sure that the superscript is high enough in this case:
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}}
%Use a separate algorithm for single symbols:
\newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}}
\newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
%Enable nesting of accents:
    \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent
%If there's more than a single symbol, use the first character instead (see below):
    \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi
%Determine the italic correction:
    \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}%
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%
    \dimen@\wd\tw@
    \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
%Now \dimen@ is the italic correction of the symbol.
    \divide\dimen@ 3
    \@tempdima\wd\tw@
    \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace
%Now \@tempdima is the width of the symbol.
    \divide\@tempdima 10
    \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima
%Now \dimen@ = (italic correction / 3) - (Breite / 10)
    \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi
%The bar will be shortened in the case \dimen@<0 !
    \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@
    \if#31
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%
      \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna
%Place the combined final kern (-\dimen@) if it is >0 or if a superscript follows:
      \let\final@kern#2%
      \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi
      \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi
    \else
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}%
    \fi
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
%The following initialises \macc@kerna and calls \mathaccent:
  \if#31
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \else
%If the argument consists of more than one symbol, and if the first token is
%a letter, use that letter for the computations:
    \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%
    \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#1\endmarker
    \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else
      \def\first@char{}%
    \fi
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\test[1]{%
$#1{\bm{A}}$
$#1{\bm{\mathcal A}}$
}

\begin{document}
\test\widebar

\test\overline
\end{document}
```

[image: Difference between widebar and overline on mathcal]

Is there an easy fix for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cause of the problem

When `\bm{A}`, `\mathcal{A}` or `\bm{\mathcal{A}}` entered into `\widebar`, they will fail the `\if@single` test, and thus produce the undesired long bar.

## Solution

1. Typeset the symbol without the accent.
2. Add the accent over a `\phantom` version of the symbol, in which we *must* force a `\if@single` version to be used.
3. Fine-tune the position of the accent with `\mathllap` from the [`mathtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package, and some negative space `\!`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
% Hendrik Vogt's widebar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253/164314
\makeatletter
\let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent
\newcommand*\if@single[3]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%
  \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}%
  \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
  }
%The bar will be moved to the right by a half of \macc@kerna, which is computed by amsmath:
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
%If there's a superscript following the bar, then no negative kern may follow the bar;
%an additional {} makes sure that the superscript is high enough in this case:
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}}
%Use a separate algorithm for single symbols:
\newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}}
\newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
%Enable nesting of accents:
    \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent
%If there's more than a single symbol, use the first character instead (see below):
    \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi
%Determine the italic correction:
    \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}%
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%
    \dimen@\wd\tw@
    \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
%Now \dimen@ is the italic correction of the symbol.
    \divide\dimen@ 3
    \@tempdima\wd\tw@
    \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace
%Now \@tempdima is the width of the symbol.
    \divide\@tempdima 10
    \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima
%Now \dimen@ = (italic correction / 3) - (Breite / 10)
    \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi
%The bar will be shortened in the case \dimen@<0 !
    \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@
    \if#31
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%
      \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna
%Place the combined final kern (-\dimen@) if it is >0 or if a superscript follows:
      \let\final@kern#2%
      \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi
      \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi
    \else
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}%
    \fi
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
%The following initialises \macc@kerna and calls \mathaccent:
  \if#31
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \else
%If the argument consists of more than one symbol, and if the first token is
%a letter, use that letter for the computations:
    \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%
    \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#1\endmarker
    \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else
      \def\first@char{}%
    \fi
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\test[1]{%
$#1{\bm{A}}$
$#1{\bm{\mathcal A}}$
}

% My implementation starts here
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
% Forcing a \if@single version but keep the flexibility of a following superscript
\newcommand\widebarbm[1]{%
  \@ifnextchar^{%
    {\bm{#1}\mathllap{\wide@bar@{\phantom{\!\bm{#1}}}{0}{1}}}}%
  {%
    \bm{#1}\mathllap{\wide@bar@{\phantom{\!\bm{#1}}}{1}{1}}}%
}
\newcommand\widebarcal[1]{%
  \@ifnextchar^{%
    {\mathcal{#1}\mathllap{\wide@bar@{\phantom{\!\mathcal{#1}}}{0}{1}}}}%
  {%
    \mathcal{#1}\mathllap{\wide@bar@{\phantom{\!\mathcal{#1}}}{1}{1}}}%
}
\newcommand\widebarbmcal[1]{%
  \@ifnextchar^{%
    {\bm{\mathcal{#1}}\mathllap{\wide@bar@{\phantom{\!\bm{\mathcal{#1}}}}{0}{1}}}}%
  {%
    \bm{\mathcal{#1}}\mathllap{\wide@bar@{\phantom{\!\bm{\mathcal{#1}}}}{1}{1}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\test\widebar

\test\overline

\bigskip

New versions below: 
\begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
\hline
$\widebarbm{A}$       & by \verb|$\widebarbm{A}$|      \\
\hline
$\widebarbm{B}^a$     & by \verb|$\widebarbm{B}^a$|    \\
\hline
$\widebarcal{A}$      & by \verb|$\widebarcal{A}$|     \\
\hline
$\widebarcal{B}^a$    & by \verb|$\widebarcal{B}^a$|   \\
\hline
$\widebarbmcal{A}$    & by \verb|$\widebarbmcal{A}$|   \\
\hline
$\widebarbmcal{B}^a$  & by \verb|$\widebarbmcal{B}^a$| \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]