# Vector: Bold and arrow sign on top

Tags: vector

Consider I have a vector x containing different x_i values. I want x to be both **blond** and have **arrow sign** on top. But if I use `$\vv\textbf{x}}$` the font of  x would be different from the fonts of elements,x_i, in the vector.

**Question:** How can I define a bold vector x that has arrow on top and has the same font as the element `x_i`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. `\mathbf` instead of `\textbf`. Are you using `esvect` package? And I am sure you don't want **blond** vectors ;-)

Comment: What's wrong with blond vectors? ;)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you; but even if I use \vv{\mathbf {x}}, its font would be different from x_i. How can I make them both have the same font?

Comment: @AdrianAd: Yes, it won't work with `\mathbf` due to the vector arrow. Didn't thought about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\mathbf` seems to be wrong for vector symbols, at least in conjunction with `esvect` package style vectors (`\vv`) command.

By the way: `esvect` provides eight different styles of arrows to be selected with `\usepackage[a]{esvect}` up to `\usepackage[h]{esvect}`. `[d]` is default.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{esvect}


\begin{document}


$\vv{\textbf{x}} \longrightarrow$ wrong

$\vv{\mathbf{x}} \longrightarrow$ still wrong

$\vv{\bm{x}} \longrightarrow$ correct


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: Package `esvect`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\boldsymbol{x}` defined in the `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$$\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{x}} \rightarrow x_i$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: egreg will scold you for using `\boldsymbol`, I fear

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I see there's discussion here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10643/88563 . I'm new, should I delete my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You want `\usepackage{bm}` and `\vec{\bm{x}}`