# \ThisStyle, \SavedStyle and \bm

Tags: math-mode, boxes, bm

I think this is a follow-up to [How to capture the current math style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78872/how-to-capture-the-current-math-style).

In this MWE, `\bm{\testbox}` works when used after `\testbox`. But it does not work on its own (commented line):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,bm}
\newcommand{\testbox}{\ThisStyle{\mbox{$\SavedStyle X$}}}
\begin{document}
    $\testbox \bm{\testbox}$
%   $\bm{\testbox}$
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\ThisStyle #1->\ifmmode \def \@mmode 
                                     {T}\mathchoice {\edef \m@switch {D}\LMe...
l.6     $\bm{\testbox}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I have found out that this works:

```
    $\ThisStyle{\@gobble\SavedStyle} \bm{\testbox}$
```

But I have no idea, why :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this well received answer, [\bm package versus \boldsymbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/bm-package-versus-boldsymbol/10643#10643), Philippe points out that sometimes, because of the way `\bm` is defined, it needs an extra set of braces about its argument.  Thus,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,bm}
\newcommand{\testbox}{\ThisStyle{\mbox{$\SavedStyle X$}}}
\begin{document}
    $\testbox \bm{\testbox}$
    $\scriptstyle\bm{{\testbox}}$
\end{document}
```

produces the desired result.

[image]

Comment: Hey, we've met before :) I did not dare to add this to my previous question because it just seemed to be too much of a special case. However, this applies very well to that other question. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks!  I'm real proud of my `\ThisStyle` macro, which can usually condense the syntax compared to the corresponding `\mathchoice`. Best wishes in its use.