# Location of superscript in LaTeX

Tags: superscripts

From the attached figure, you can see the star on the left-hand side is higher than the star on the right-hand side. Is it possible to lower the star on the left to the same height as the right-hand side?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
    \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^{*} = \hat{\beta}^{*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is [better to use the `bm` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/bm-package-versus-boldsymbol) for bold math italics, as it gets the positioning of accents and the spacing for sub- and superscripts right.

The `bm` package will also redefine `\boldsymbol`, so you don't have to replace all `\boldsymbol` with `\bm` throughout the document.  Therefore, make sure to load `bm` *after* `amsbsy`, which is loaded by `amsmath`.  Still, I find it highly appealing to use `\bm` as it has only two letters as opposed to the ten letters of `\boldsymbol`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}
\[
    \hat{\bm{\beta}}^{*} = \hat{\beta}^{*}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

Add a `{}` and superscript that.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
    \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}{}^{*} = \hat{\beta}^{*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if one still wanted an unbolded hat, but better kerning, perhaps this addition, as well:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
    \hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}\mkern4mu}\mkern-4mu{}^{*} = \hat{\beta}^{*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Both techniques can be adopted into this macro approach of `\hatonboldsymbol[mu-shift]{character}`

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\hatonboldsymbol[2][0]{\hat{\boldsymbol{#2}\mkern#1mu}\mkern-#1mu{}}
\begin{document}
\[
    \hatonboldsymbol[4]{\beta}_1^{*} = \hat{\beta}_1^{*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]