# Lualatex and bm package

Tags: math-mode, luatex, bold, bm

I've updated my latex packages yesterday and have now issues with `lualatex`. One problem arising for me now is, that `lualatex` does not print bold characters using the `bm` package.

When I compile the following MWE with pdflatex everything looks okay, but for lualatex it doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
%
Bold $\bm{E}$
\\
Normal $E$
%
\end{document}
```

Output using pdflatex

[image]

using lualatex

[image]

Also trying to fall back to an earlier version of lualatex by using `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` does not work for me.

When having a look at the log file, there are the suspicious messages

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 142.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bm on input line 208.
[...]
Missing character: There is no х (U+0445) in font cmmi10!
```

Can anyone tell me, what is going on here and what I need to do to solve this problem, since I am quite sure `lualatex` and `bm` worked before?

Comment: `\bm` tries to produce the Unicode character `U+0445` instead of `\mathchar30021`.  It should work if you load `unicode-math`.  Apart from that, I consider this a regression.

Comment: lualatex is increasingly incompatible with tex so this sort of thing is more or less expected. Although that is I think older change not the luatex8x-9x changes that the luatex85 package addresses.  I had some version of bm working for a test release of luatex at one point last year but then the mathcode handling changed again (it changed several times in development:-) I can probably update bm now texlive 2016 is stable (but with luatex you should probably be using unicode-math and bm will not work with that)

Comment: @HenriMenke a bug in what? if you use a program written for tex with a system that takes a similar input syntax but entirely different behaviour and find the program does not work, is that a bug in the program, or user error?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry :(  I changed »bug« into »regression«.  `bm` is a great package!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle since I'm nearly finished with my thesis and have a submission date, changing all over to unicode-math is actually not an option. :-/

Comment: @JMP if you are using luatex and at that stage I would seriously consider staying at texlive 2015 (or in your case texlive 2014?). luatex has introduced _multiple_ massively incompatible changes to both its tex and lua interfaces, we've tried to smooth most of the problems before texlive 2016 goes live, but some problems are inevitable, especially broken packages whose authors we can't reach (which doesn't apply to bm, but still....)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I need to see, how to get around lualatex. I basically need this to generate a few figures which display some data Latex cannot handle otherwise. Probably I come along with externalising this graphics.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The patch below has been incorporated into the distributed `bm.sty` 2016/07/07 v1.2b

---

Here is an update for `bm` in luatex using *classic* math font setup. It does not do the right thing for opentype math fonts with unicode-math (where it is not always clear what the right thing should be as most such setups do not include a bold font)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}

\makeatletter
\def\bm@test@token#1{%
  \let\bm@next\@empty
  \ifx#1\@@end
  \else\ifx#1\mathchoice
    \let\bm@next\bm@mathchoice
  \else\ifx#1\mathchar
    \afterassignment\bm@mathchar\count@
  \else\ifx#1\mathaccent
    \afterassignment\bm@mathaccent\count@
  \else\ifx#1\delimiter
    \afterassignment\bm@delimiter\count@
  \else\ifx#1\radical
    \afterassignment\bm@radical\count@
  \else\ifx#1\mkern
    \bm@register#1{\muskip\z@}%
  \else\ifx#1\kern
    \bm@register#1\skip@
  \else\ifx#1\penalty
    \bm@register#1\count@
  \else\ifx#1\unvcopy
    \let\bm@next\bm@add
  \else\ifcat\noexpand#1\relax
    \xdef\meaning@{\meaning#1}%
    \expandafter\bm@mchar@test\meaning@""""\@nil#1%
  \else\ifcat.\ifcat a#1.\else#1\fi
    \count@\mathcode`#1\relax
    \ifnum\count@=\mathcode`\'%
      \begingroup\uccode`\~`#1\uppercase{\endgroup
        \def\bm@next{\bm@expand~}}%
    \else
      \ifx\bm@previous\left
        \count@\delcode`#1\relax
        \bm@delimiter
      \else
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \ifnum\count@>"8000
\Umathcharnumdef\@tempa\count@
\xdef\meaning@{\meaning\@tempa}%
\expandafter\bm@mchar@test\meaning@""""\@nil\@tempa
\else
        \bm@mathchar
\fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \fi
    \fi
  \else
    \bm@add{#1}%
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
  \bm@next}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
%
Bold $\bm{E\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)}$
\\
Normal $E\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)$
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

<sup>[This is not a solution but a workaround]</sup>

You say, that there is an upcoming deadline and there might be no fix available until then.  Here is a workaround, which requires the `amsmath` package (which you most probably use).  It defines `\bm` to use the `\boldsymbol` macro from `amsbsy` (loaded automatically by `amsmath`).  Keep in mind that there are certain [drawbacks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238) compared to `bm`, but at least the symbols show up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\bm{\boldsymbol}
\begin{document}
\luatexbanner

Bold $\bm{E}$

Normal $E$
\end{document}
```

[image]