# Why doesn't the 'bm' package work with the 'unicode-math' package?

Tags: math-mode, bold, unicode-math, bm

I want the bold italic math character (as in normal math) in math mode. So, I tried to use the `bm` package but it doesn't work together with the `unicode-math` package in my LaTeX document. Again, for some specific characters, it is not possible to remove `unicode-math` package. Can someone help me to use those packages together? Thanks!

The following codes work properly without `\usepackage{unicode-math}`. But when adding this package, the `\bm` command doesn't work.

```
  \documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{bm}
  \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
  \usepackage{color, colortbl}
  \usepackage{pgf, pgfplots}
  \usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
  \usepackage{mathrsfs}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage{geometry}

  \begin{document}
      $\bm{(\sqrt[n]{x})^{n}=\sqrt[n]{x^{n}}=x}$
  \end{document}
```

Comment: I have no experience with the issue but from questions here on the site I recall that `bm` and `unicode-math` are in fact quite incompatible. On the other hand if you are using `xetex` or `luatex` you should't have any need for `bm` in the first place.

Comment: you shouldn't load inputenc, fontenc, lmodern when using lualatex or xelatex. And no bm doesn't work with unicode-math see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315389/2388

Comment: As the order matters with `unicode-math` you should also indicate in the MWE where you would load `unicode-math`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, some general comments and observations about the code shown in your preamble:

- When using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you should *not* load the `fontenc` and `inputenc` packages. (Even when using pdfLaTeX, it's no longer necessary to load the `inputenc` package *unless* your file's input encoding is *not* UTF8 or ASCII, which is a proper subset of UTF8.)
- Loading the `colortbl` and `color` packages independently is a mistake, as it doesn't maximize the compatibility and interoperability of these two packages. Hence, do replace `\usepackage{color, colortbl}` with `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. See section 2.1.2, "Package options", as well as Table 1, "Package options", of the user guide of the `xcolor` package for more information.
- When using the `unicode-math` package along with a suitable OpenType math font (specified via a suitable `\setmathfont` instruction), there's no need to load the following packages: `lmodern`, `fontspec`, `amsmath`, `amsfonts`, `amssymb`, and `bm`. (Aside: If you load the `unicode-math` package but do not run a `\setmathfont` directive, the default math font is `Latin Modern Math`.)
- The `unicode-math` package loads the `amsmath` package automatically if it hasn't already been loaded *prior* to LaTeX encountering the instruction `\usepackage{unicode-math}`. See Section 3, "Getting Started", of the
  user guide of `unicode-math` package for more information.
- If you wish to use the `\mathscr` directive of the `mathrsfs` package, be sure to load `mathrsfs` *after* `unicode-math`. (I mention this because the preamble you posted loads the `mathrsfs` package.)

Now, finally, to the main part of your query:

> I want the bold italic math character (as in normal math) in math mode

- To generate ***bold italic*** math-mode letters and symbols, the `unicode-math` package provides a macro called `\symbfit`. Use it in lieu of `\boldsymbol` and `\bm`. (As you've discovered, `\bm` doesn't work anyway; hence, don't use it.)
- To generate **bold upright** math-mode letters and symbols, use `\symbfup`. Use it in lieu of `\mathbf`.

As the following screenshot demonstrates, `\symbfit` and `\symbfup` -- as well as their regular-weight counterparts `\symit` and `\symup` -- affect the weight and shape of Latin and Greek letters, but *not* the shape and weight of (math) "operators" such as `\int`, `\sum`, `\exp`, and `\ln`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} 
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\newcommand\blurb{(\sqrt[n]{x}\,)^{n}=\sqrt[n]{x^{n}}=x 
     \quad \alpha\beta\Sigma\Omega \quad \int\sum\exp\ln}

\usepackage{setspace}  % just for this example
\setstretch{1.25}

\begin{document}
\obeylines
$\blurb$ --- default
$\symbfit{\blurb}$ --- \verb+\symbfit+
$\symbfup{\blurb}$ --- \verb+\symbfup+
$\symit{\blurb}$ --- \verb+\symit+
$\symup{\blurb}$ --- \verb+\symup+
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought the Latin Modern unicode fonts were those loaded by default with Lua(La)TeX. Is that not the case? I don't know for Xe(La)TeX

Comment: @FranckPastor - That's what I wrote: "If you load the `unicode-math` package but do not run a `\setmathfont` directive, the default math font is `Latin Modern Math`." I guess I failed to mention that `Latin Modern Roman` will be the default main or "roman" (upright) *text* font if no `\setmainfont` directive is provided. Tut tut. I provided explicit `\setmainfont` and `\setmathfont` directives mainly to make it (hopefully utterly) straightforward for future readers of this answer to determine where they should "hook in" to change the text and math fonts to suit their own typesetting needs.

Comment: I believe `unicode-math` now loads `amsmath`.

Comment: @Davislor - You're absolutely right! I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @FranckPastor no,  xelatex and lualatex default to classic 8bit math fonts unless you load unicode-math, even though they default to latin modern opentype unicode fonts for text

Answer (score 5):

The `bm` package is for legacy 8-bit fonts.  In `unicode-math`, load a math font that comes in bold (currently, XITS Math, Libertinus Math or Minion Math) and use `\boldsymbol` for bold operators and signs.  If you only need bold letters, you can use `\mathbf`, `\mathbfcal`, etc. Or the new commands `\symbfup` for bold upright, `\symbfit` for bold italic, etc., as Mico brought up. Bold letters work with any Unicode math font.

If you want to bold symbols and a different math font, you can also load a bold math font with `\setmathfont[version=bold]{SomeBoldMathFont.otf}`.

You’re loading a number of legacy packages that are obsolete with `unicode-math`, among them `amssymb`, `amsfonts`, `mathrsfs`, `fontenc` and `inputenc`.  All of these are only needed if you’re using legacy 7- and 8-bit fonts. (You shouldn’t be loading `inputenc` in any case: XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX don’t support it, and PDFLaTeX no longer needs it.)

Comment: for unicode mmath fonts that have a separate bold font `\bm` could work, it mostly fails as the usual assumption in unicode-math  is that the bold symbols come from plane 1 in the same font, and `bm` doesn't play that game.