# Fixing interaction of `bm` and NFSS

Tags: math-mode, math-fonts, bm

I’m trying to get math boldified in less fragile way that what `bm` would do.  (Compare with [the last paragraphs in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10643/81006).)

However, after hours of reading sources of NFSS (not for the first time!  Maybe even not the 10th!) every time it looks like my understanding is not enough to predict what would work (with “math versions”), and what wouldn’t.  In particular, the minimal example below seems to work, but I cannot explain why — so I do not know whether it would continue to work in more complicated situations.

**Questions:**

1. How to explain why the part of code marked as `works only if…` below works?
2. Is there a more robust way to extract which “Math alphabet” (like `\mathfrak`) is currently active?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{bm}

\makeatletter
\def\grabCurFam#1#2{%   A replacement for \install@mathalphabet \mathbf {DEF} DEF=\select@group 4args OR ...\use@mathgroup \M@U {10}
    \grabCurFamA {#1}#2\use@mathgroup{}{-10}\@nil       % -10 is not a valid
  }
\def\grabCurFamA #1#2\use@mathgroup#3#4#5\@nil{%
    \ifnum #4>-10 %
      \ifnum \the\fam = #4 \gdef\grabbedAlphabet{#1}%       \show #1%
      \fi
    \fi
  }
\def\grabMathAlphabet{%
  \begingroup           % does not create an empty math atom???
  \xdef\grabbedAlphabet{\noexpand\fam\the\fam       % works only if family number is the same in normal/bold math versions,
                                                        % and the font is already preloaded.  However, in simplest examples these
                                                        % conditions actually seam to hold.
                  \noexpand\PackageWarning{--inline--}{Could not grab the current math alphabet for math version=\the\fam}}%
  \let\install@mathalphabet\grabCurFam
  \let\getanddefine@fonts\@gobbletwo
  \csname mv@\math@version\endcsname
  \PackageWarning{--inline--}{got: \meaning\grabbedAlphabet}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\bmdefine\BgSimple{g}
\bmdefine\BgHairy{{\grabbedAlphabet{g_{\text{\the\fam}}}}}  % Infinite loop without enclosing braces!!! ???
\def\gBM{\ifnum\the\fam<0 \expandafter\BgSimple\else{}_{\text{\the\fam}}\grabMathAlphabet\expandafter\BgHairy\fi}

\begin{document}
%\tracingall

% To debug: preloading frak breaks the match of the family numbers between normal/bold math versions.
$\vphantom{\mathfrak{g}}  1 g \gBM$

$2 \mathrm{g \gBM}$

$2' \mathsf{g \gBM}$

$2'' \mathcal{g \gBM}$

$2''' \mathfrak{g \gBM}$

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot] (The subscripts are math-family numbers)

Comment: I am not sure that you _want_ this to work. By design `\mathxx`  commands do not combine in the way text font commands do. Even without `bm` `\mathit{\mathbf{g}}` is _not_ bold italic, it is  just the outer math alphabet that has an effect and it is normal weight italic. Similarly I would expect (and the package documents) that  `\mathfrak{\bm{g}}` will give a normal weight fraktur g.

Comment: Sorry David, but I do not see how combinability of `\mathALPH` commands has anything to do with `\bm` — which **is** combinable with `\mathALPH` **provided** it is combined in the opposite order.

Comment: `\bm{g}` is designed to work like `g` except using a bold math italic font. so it is just exactly as if you had  defined `\mathbfit{g}`  in particular `\mathfrak{\bm{g}}` works like `\mathfrak{\mathbfit{g}}` and is the same as `\mathfrak{g}` by design. So you could ask how to **change** bm but not how to **fix** it as it is not a bug.

Comment: conversely `\bm{\mathfrak{g}}` is designed to work like `\mathfrak{g}` except using a bold fraktur.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you have a typo in your [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448609/fixing-interaction-of-bm-and-nfss#comment1127171_448609): `\mathit{\mathbf{g}}` does not give "normal weight italic" but it gives "bold weight upright" (i.e.only the **inner** math alphabet counts in the end in the case of nesting).

Answer (score 1):

In general, the approach you want is to load separate bold alphabets such as `\mathbfcal` for bold calligraphic and `\mathbfit` for bold italic. The names vary slightly from package to package, so check the documentation.

If you are able to use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, I recommend writing new documents with `unicode-math`.

If you need or prefer to use PDFLaTeX, and need all those alphabets, a good solution is to load both `isomath` (for bold and sans-serif math alphabets that include Greek) and `mathalfa` (for script, calligraphic, Fraktur and double-struck). Both make a comprehensive set of NFSS fonts available.

An alternative is `mathastext`, which also enables you to use any legacy text font plus any LGR-encoded Greek font for math letters.

I am not aware of any solution that would still work when you declare a new custom math alphabet.