# Regarding math fonts

Tags: fonts, amsmath, math-fonts

I'm having troubles understanding where to read some documentation about how to set different math fonts and where to look for some of the most popular. I don't mean font styles or families, but different fonts like in LyX where I can set, for instance, Crimson (New TX), Euler VM, Iwona (Math), etc. [image]

I'm using pdflatex/biber to compile my document, I don't know if that's relevant. My goal is to try many different fonts and pick the best one for my taste as I have to type many different math symbols and I don't like the result of the default math font.

I feel like I have missed something important, can you give me some hints/references. Thanks

Comment: A math setup consists of more than one font: symbols, letters, digits, math alphabets etc can all be from different fonts. This means that there are endless possible combinations. I'm not aware of some comprehensive, up-to-date overview (which doesn't imply that it doesn't exist somewhere). You could start  to review the packages on ctan: https://ctan.org/topic/font-maths

Comment: If you want to use Unicode system fonts later (e.g., for Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols code block, etc), you can look at `unicode-math` package. You will need to compile with xelatex/lualatex. Start with the legacy fonts for pdflatex, though, as that will give good background context for the concepts being used in the Unicode space by fonts like Asana Math, Fira Math, XITS Math, and others.

Comment: @Cicada What are the legacy fonts? Where can I read about them?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, I'm going to look at your link

Comment: @Luca Hmm, the CTAN page has both legacy (8-bit) fonts and modern ones. Section 4.3 of `isomath` (do `texdoc isomath`) describes things from an overall perspective - see Table 5, in particular. Perhaps it is better to start with modern fonts and `unicode-math` package (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448609/fixing-interaction-of-bm-and-nfss). The limited number of slots in legacy fonts leads to somewhat intricate methods for dealing with all the glyphs needed. The historical background can wait, to be practical.