# Writing mathematical symbol with bold

Tags: math-mode

I want to write `\gamma` with bold, for this  I use `\mathbf{\gamma}` but the result that I have is not with bold. How can I fix this problem. someone can help me?

Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage[mathcal]{eucal} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\setstretch{1,4} 
\begin{document}

Définissons également le vecteur colonne

 $$\mathbf{\gamma}_c(t)=(\gamma_c^{(u,l,0,0)}(t),\gamma_c^{(u,l,1,0)}(t),...,\gamma_c^{(u,l,1,d)}(t),...,\gamma_c^{(u,l,k,0)}(t),...,\gamma_c^{(u,l,k,d)}(t))^{'}_{1*((d+1)k+1)}$$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\bm{\gamma}` `(bm` package)

Comment: thank you i will try it.

Comment: no results with \ bm{}

Comment: then you are using a non standard font set, or you are doing something wrong, but as you have shown no code, it is hard to know.

Comment: if you change `\mathbf` to `\bm` or `\boldsymbol` as shown in the existing answers than you get a bold gamma.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\[
\gamma
\bm{\gamma}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `\boldsymbol`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage[mathcal]{eucal} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\setstretch{1,4} 
\begin{document}

Définissons également le vecteur colonne

\[
\boldsymbol{\gamma}_c(t)=(\gamma_c^{(u,l,0,0)}(t),\gamma_c^{(u,l,1,0)}(t),...,\gamma_c^{(u,l,1,d)}(t),...,\gamma_c^{(u,l,k,0)}(t),...,\gamma_c^{(u,l,k,d)}(t))^{'}_{1*((d+1)k+1)}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: as a general rule `\bm` will give a better result than `\boldsymbol` (akthough the same in this case)

Comment: I agree totally with David: see this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/bm-package-versus-boldsymbol

Comment: why it works correctly with big gamma \ Gamma but no result with small gamma \gamma ?

Comment: @salime Can you please show the code that causes the problem with the small \gamma?

Comment: @salime you have two answers now that show complete documents (and bold gammas) if you are not getting bold, edit your question to make a similar complete example document that shows the problem

Comment: this is the code $$\mathbf{\gamma}_c(t)=(\gamma_c^{(u,l,0,0)}(t),\gamma_c^{(u,l,1,0)}(t),...,\gamma_c^{(u,l,1,d)}(t),...,\gamma_c^{(u,l,k,0)}(t),...,\gamma_c^{(u,l,k,d)}(t))^{'}_{1*((d+1)k+1)}$$

Comment: @salime not the problem, but don't use `$$` for equations

Comment: @salime replacing `\mathbf` with `\boldsymbol` gives a bold \gamma for me. Maybe you have some problematic package. Can you make a small document that reproduces your problem?

Comment: @salime that is not a complete document and it is not added as an edit to your question, You need to provide something that people can run and debug why you are not getting a bold font, it will be unrelated to the expression you have shown in that comment but related to your font setup in the preamble. `mathptmx` for example has no bold math fonts, if you are using that.

Comment: this is a part of my document latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[mathcal]{eucal}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setstretch{1,4}

\begin{document}

Comment: Définissons également le vecteur colonne 
$$\mathbf{\gamma}_c(t)=(\gamma_c^{(u,l,0,0)}(t),\gamma_c^{(u,l,1,0)}(t),...,\gamma_c^{(u,l,1,d)}(t),...,\gamma_c^{(u,l,k,0)}(t),...,\gamma_c^{(u,l,k,d)}(t))^{'}_{1*((d+1)k+1)}$$

\end{document}

Comment: @salime Works fine with `\boldsymbol` and replacing `$$...$$` with `\[...\]`

Comment: i think that i have a problem of my package

Comment: @salime It would be helpful if you could tell us which package. The packages you showed work good enough (there are a few warnings which you should fix)

Comment: @salime do not post code in comments (it does not make a readable result) edit your question and add a _complete_ document that shows the problem

Comment: Thank you for your efforts

Comment: Thanks everyone, the problem is solved after downloading the \bm package from CTAN. I think that the problem was my old package that does not work properly.