# Bold mathematical symbols

Tags: bold, boldmath

I am trying to write a greek letter in bold using `\mathbf{}` but it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

I wrote:

```
\mathbf{\pi} = (\pi_1, \dots, \pi_k)^{T}
```

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Just use `\boldsymbol{foo}`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Comment: I recommend `\bm{\pi}` (requires `\usepackage{bm}`) instead of `\boldsymbol`. See here for the reason why: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/bm-package-versus-boldsymbol/10643#10643