# How to make bold text more visible

Tags: math-mode, fonts, boldmath

I designed a T-shirt in OpenOffice and wasn't happy with the rendering of a lower case Gamma. I tried doing it in LaTeX, and neither the formula nor the text is as visible as the OpenOffice version. The markup I'm using is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in,paperwidth=10in,top=0.75in, bottom=0in, left=0in, right=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\vspace{.5in}

\begin{center}
 {\Huge \bfseries Which part of}
\end{center}

\vspace{1.75in}

 {\Huge
   \[
     \bm{(\gamma^{\mu } (i\hbar \partial _{\mu } - {\frac {e}{c}}A_{\mu })-mc) \psi =0}
   \]
 }

\vspace{1.75in}

\begin{center}
 {\Huge \bfseries don't you understand?}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in,paperwidth=10in,top=0.75in, bottom=0in, left=0in, right=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

\setmainfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}[
  version=bold,
  FakeBold=2.0,
  FakeStretch = 1.1 ]

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}[
  version=bold,
  FakeBold=2.0,
  FakeStretch = 1.1 ]

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\vspace{.5in}

\begin{center}
 {\Huge \bfseries Which part of}
\end{center}

\vspace{1.75in}

 {\Huge
   \[
      \boldsymbol{\gamma^{\mu } (i\hbar \partial _{\mu } - {\frac {e}{c}}A_{\mu })-mc) \psi =0}
   \]
 }

\vspace{1.75in}
```

and got

```
shmuel@linux-gn5l:~> latexmk -xelatex ~/Documents/Dirac
Rc files read:
  /etc/texmf/latexmk/latexmk.conf
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 Apr. 2020, version: 4.69a.
Latexmk: applying rule 'xelatex'...
Rule 'xelatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'xelatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'xelatex'
------------
------------
Running 'xelatex -no-pdf -recorder  "/home/shmuel/Documents/Dirac.tex"'
------------
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/TeX Live for opensuse.org) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/home/shmuel/Documents/Dirac.tex
LaTeX2e 
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3deprecation.def))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/ucharcat/ucharcat.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)
! Undefined control sequence.
 \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Erroneous variable \c__fontspec_shape_n_n_tl used!
l.3806 \emfontdeclare{ \emshape, \eminnershape }
                                                
?
```

Answer (score 3):

That’s the bold font of Computer Modern.  If you switch to LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, and you really want to do this to Computer Modern, you can use `fontspec` options to thicken and stretch the math font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in,paperwidth=10in,top=0.75in, bottom=0in, left=0in, right=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}[
  version=bold,
  FakeBold=2.0,
  FakeStretch = 1.1 ]

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\vspace{.5in}

\begin{center}
 {\Huge \bfseries Which part of}
\end{center}

\vspace{1.75in}

 {\Huge
   \[
      \boldsymbol{\gamma^{\mu } (i\hbar \partial _{\mu } - {\frac {e}{c}}A_{\mu })-mc) \psi =0}
   \]
 }

\vspace{1.75in}

\begin{center}
 {\Huge \bfseries don't you understand?}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't \boldsymbol deprecated? How do I also expnad and thicken the text? Thanks.

Comment: @shmuel  You would expand and thicken the text with `\setmainfont{NewCM10-Bold}[FakeBold=...., FakeStretch=...]` with your values of choice. This sets the main font; you would wrap the options in `BoldFeatures={...}` to keep using `\bfseries`.

Comment: I haven’t heard anything about `\boldsymbol` from `amsmath` being deprecated. It’s completely compatible with either `bm` or `unicode-math`.

Comment: In addition to p.13 of the documentation at <https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf>, I got two hits searching for 'boldsymbol deprecated. I  have no idea how seriously to take them.

Comment: Please see my edit. I tried puting the console log inside a pre tag pair and the formatting is strange; what is the correct way to mark it? Thanks.

Comment: @shmuel `\bm` does some things better than `\boldsymbol`, but some other things are worse. (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10643/82917) In general I concede that `\bm` is slightly better in the "important" things (e.g. with the italic correction) and therefore its pros win over the cons, but I wouldn't go as far as denoting `\boldymbol` as "deprecated". You should only keep in mind that the `bm` package does `\let\boldsymbol\bm`, so if you load `bm` after `amsmath` then you lose the difference.

Comment: @shmuel Thanks for the ref. I use `\boldsymbol` in my own code, since I either want to compile with `bm` in PDFTeX or `unicode-math` , and that’s what works right in both. LaTeX will never drop support for it, and it gives the correct output.

Comment: @shmuel There isn’t a newer synonym for it in `unicode-math`. If you want to avoid `\boldsymbol`, since you’re emboldening the entire equation, you could switch to `\boldmath` instead.