# {amsmath} \mathbf not formatting variables correctly

Tags: amsmath, boldmath, boldsymbol

I incorrectly thought that in `{amsmath}` the proper way to bold an equation or expression was `\mathbf`.

Actually, in this case the solutions in the exercise are highlighted and bolded:

[image]

My command syntax is `\hl{$=\mathbf{answer_here}$}`

Please advise re: the proper way to highlight/bold the solution so as to preserve formatting of the variable.

Thanks very much for your support!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.3in,include head]{geometry} %changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Problem Set D}
{}
{Due 04/07/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
\noindent 
 
 \bigskip
 \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\newlength{\lwidth}% added
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)} % added

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
 after-skip=2cm,
 label-width=\lwidth, %<--------- changed 
 item-indent= 2.2em,%<--------- changed
 label=(\arabic*),
 column-sep=1em  %<----------
}
\begin{document}
 %definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
 \def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

\textbf{Simplify.}
\begin{tasks}
 [style=enumerate](3)
% Prob #1
\task 
$\sqrt{27}$
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=\sqrt{9}\sqrt{3}$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{3\sqrt{3}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
 
 % Prob #2
 \task 
 $3\sqrt{48}$
 \vspace{3mm}
 \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
  $=3\sqrt{16}\sqrt{3}$
  \bigskip
  $(3)(4)\sqrt{3}$
  \bigskip
  \hl{$=\mathbf{12\sqrt{3}}$}
 \end{solutionorbox}
 \vspace{0.25cm}
 
 % Prob #3
 \task 
 $5\sqrt{12}$
 \vspace{3mm}
 \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
  $=5\sqrt{4}\sqrt{3}$
  \bigskip
  $=(5)(2)\sqrt{3}$
  \bigskip
  \hl{$=\mathbf{10\sqrt{3}}$}
 \end{solutionorbox}
 \vspace{0.25cm}
 
 % Prob #4
 \task 
 $\sqrt{x^{10}}$ 
 \vspace{3mm}
 \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
  $=\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}$
  \bigskip
  $=(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)$
  \bigskip
  \hl{$=\mathbf{x^5=x^{10\div2}}$}
 \end{solutionorbox}
 \vspace{0.25cm}
 
 % Prob #5
 \task 
 $\sqrt{a^{4}b^{12}}$ 
 \vspace{3mm}
 \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
  $=(a^{4\div2})(b^{12\div2})$
  \bigskip
  \hl{$=\mathbf{b^6x^2}$}
 \end{solutionorbox}
 \vspace{0.25cm}
 
 % Prob #6
 \task 
 $2a^2\sqrt{a^8}$ 
 \vspace{3mm}
 \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
  $=(2a^2)(a^{8\div2})$
  \bigskip
  $=(2a^2)(a^4)$
  \bigskip
  \hl{$=\mathbf{2a^{2+4}=2a^6}$}
 \end{solutionorbox}
 \vspace{0.25cm}
 
\end{tasks}
\vspace{0.25cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems that `\bm` can do the trick. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01SPY.png)

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry You are correct! Thanks very much for the assist. I up-voted your response but don't see anywhere where I can credit you with the "Solution".

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry  What syntax are you using for ```\bm```. When I used this command ```\hl{$=\bm{3\sqrt{3}}$}```, I got this argument error: ```<argument> =\bm```

Comment: Exactly what you wrote. But do mind to `\usepackage{bm}`. See my answer below :-)

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry  Absolutely correct again. I had forgotten to add the ```\usepackage{bm}```  Thanks very much for including the link to the article as well as the image of the "obtained result". Very much appreciated. (PS I checked your answer as the "Solution".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\bm` instead of `\mathbf` can do the trick (make sure to `\usepackage{bm}`).

Example:

```
\hl{$=\bm{3\sqrt{3}}$}
```

Here is the obtained result:

[image: Result]

> [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/234654) is quite interesting and comprehensive about `\bm` and its friends. One typical use of `\bm` for me is to get the bold Greek letter.

Comment: In the interest of simplicity, am I correct that it makes sense to replace  ```\boldsymbol{\cdot}``` with ```bm{\cdot}``` to achieve the darker multiplication operator dot?

Comment: Yes, they should be identical. More details: [comparison between `\boldsymbol` and `\bm`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3238/234654). Additionally, if you hope to get a **real** dark dot, `\bullet` can be an option (maybe not suitable for your multiplication case, though).