# How to put a big dot (and circle) over a variable?

Tags: math-mode, accents

where one can see a big dot (and circle) over W. I am using \dot{W} and \mathring{W} but seems not big enough.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
$\accentset{\bullet}{b}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This in fact answered another question of mine: How to write a big dot as in the dot product of vectore? The word 'bullet' reminded me!

Answer (score 5):

You can do the same with the amsmath package command \overset

```
\usepackage{amsmath} 

$\overset{\bullet}{W}$
```

see also the thread [How to make a larger “\dot”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/how-to-make-a-larger-dot.) to change the size of the dot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\newcommand\obullet[1]{\ensurestackMath{\stackon[1pt]{#1}{\mkern2mu\bullet}}}
\newcommand\ocirc[1]{\ensurestackMath{\stackon[1pt]{#1}{\mkern2mu\circ}}}
\begin{document}
$\ocirc{W}\obullet{x}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need it to preserve the math style...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\newcommand\obullet[1]{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackon[1pt]{\SavedStyle#1}{\SavedStyle\kern.6\LMpt\bullet}}}}
\newcommand\ocirc[1]{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackon[1pt]{\SavedStyle#1}{\SavedStyle\kern.6\LMpt\circ}}}}
\begin{document}
$\ocirc{W}\obullet{x};
\scriptstyle\ocirc{W}\obullet{x};
\scriptscriptstyle\ocirc{W}\obullet{x}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\def\overbigdot#1{\overset{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}{#1}}
```

in the preamble and then 
`\overbigdot{x}`
in the document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I suggested a different layout of your post with syntax high-lightning. Since I am required to change a minimal numbers of chars I added some words.