# Get a black \mathring symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols, accents

How can I get a black `\mathring` circle above variable, same as `\mathring`  except the circle is "filled"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put a big dot (and circle) over a variable?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18318/how-to-put-a-big-dot-and-circle-over-a-variable)

Comment: @Caradir: the bullet as accent is too big!

Answer (score 8):

Only the Latin Modern fonts allow for fonts smaller than 5pt (other
scalable font families should not need the change of family)

```
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\sbullet}{%
  \hbox{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontsize{4}{0}\selectfont\textbullet}}

$\mathring{W}\accentset{\sbullet}{W}$
```

A more general definition might be

```
\usepackage{accents}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sbullet}{%
  \hbox{\fontfamily{lmr}\fontsize{.4\dimexpr(\f@size pt)}{0}\selectfont\textbullet}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mathbullet}{\accentset{\sbullet}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Would `\dot{x}` do?

[image]

doesn't need any packages as fat as I know.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  $\overset{\bullet}{x}\quad\mathring{x}$
\end{document}
```

The placement is clearly not very satisfied compared to `\mathring`. But I think is the a solution with minimal dependence on availability of fonts. Better solutions will depend on font packages specific commands.

[image]