# Making a thicker \cdot for dot product (that is thinner than \bullet)

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm trying to replicate the dot that my professor uses in his notes for the dot product between vectors but I am having a hard time doing so. This is what it looks like:

[image]

I have tried a couple of things. `\cdot` is too thin

[image: asdf]

and `\bullet` is too thick

[image]

and using `\Large` with `\cdot` gives an error. Moreover, after digging through the list of symbols I cannot find a nice medium between `\cdot` and `\bullet`.

How can I get a dot closest to the first picture?

Comment: I use \bullet for dot products.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

May be you find a better name like `\dotp` or something like that.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\bigcdot{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{.5}}
\newcommand*\bigcdot@[2]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$a \bigcdot b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Manuel (or anyone who understands this), could you clarify a couple of points about your macros?  1. What are the two parameters to \mathpalette? (I only "see" one, unless "bigcdot@" and ".5" are separate in which case I don't understand why \mathpalette is called.  2. What ends up being the first parameter (#1) to bigcdot@, used right before \bullet?

Comment: That's how `\mathpalette` works, the `#1` that is passed to `\bigcdot@` is the current math style (`\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, or `\scriptscriptstyle` depending on the case).Basically what mathpalette does is taking two arguments, and passing the currentstyle in first place and the second argument after it, so `\mathpalete\foo{whatever}` ends up being for instance `\foo\displaystyle{whatever}`, so you have to define `\foo` accordingly.

Comment: @sardoj See [The mysteries of `\mathpalette`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34393)

Answer (score 60):

Here is a simple trick which needs the `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
a \boldsymbol{\cdot} b = 0
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

and the result is

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution; but `\bf` has been deprecated for 20+ years. Besides, `align*` serves no purpose here, where `equation*` would be the correct environment.

Comment: @egreg: Yeah! I am new to LaTex! Sorry for those! :) I changed the answer a little bit. Let me know if it is OK. :)

Comment: This answer has a downside that the other one has not: if used within the scope of a `\mathversion{bold}` (or `\boldmath`, if you prefer) declaration, the dot cannot become any bolder.  I agree, nonetheless, that it is an interesting solution.

Answer (score 14):

The following example extends Manuel's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235120/16967) in two ways:

- The vertical position is fixed to center the symbol vertically around the
  math axis as `\cdot` and `\bullet` do.
- The width of the symbol is not the scaled down width of the `\bullet`
  (with scaled down side bearings), but a little larger width of `\cdot`.

The scale and width factor can be configured by macros `\bigcdot@scalefactor` and `\bigcdot@widthfactor`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\bigcdot}{}% Check if undefined
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\bigcdot}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{}}%
}
\newcommand*{\bigcdot@scalefactor}{.5}
\newcommand*{\bigcdot@widthfactor}{1.15}
\newcommand*{\bigcdot@}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$#1\vcenter{}$}% math axis
  \sbox2{$#1\cdot\m@th$}%
  \hbox to \bigcdot@widthfactor\wd2{%
    \hfil
    \raise\ht0\hbox{%
      \scalebox{\bigcdot@scalefactor}{%
        \lower\ht0\hbox{$#1\bullet\m@th$}%
      }%
    }%
    \hfil
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ a \bigcdot b \]
%
% Comparison with \cdot and \bullet
\[ a \cdot b \bigcdot c \bullet d \]
%
% Different math styles
\[ a \bigcdot b \quad
   \scriptstyle a \bigcdot b \quad
   \scriptscriptstyle a \bigcdot b
\]
%
% Visualization of the math axis
\[
  \sbox0{${-}{\cdot}{\bigcdot}{\bullet}{-}$}
  \rlap{\copy0}%
  \vcenter{%
    \hbox{%
      \textcolor{red}{%
        \vrule width\wd0 height .05pt depth .05pt\relax
      }%
    }%
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I love it! And some more words to exceed the character limit.

Answer (score 1):

*I provide not an answer, I demonstrate a caveat of the accepted solution, in hope for a more robust solution.*

I used Heiko Oberdiek's solution, which is based on Manuel's solution. It has always worked well with the pdflatex compiler, thanks for that. But a while back I had to use the regular latex compiler, and the dot product then appears as a usual `\bullet` in the dvi file:

[image]

*2020-06-08 update*. For those interested, several solutions that work with dvi:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\dotp}{
    \mathop{
        \mathchoice{\vcenter{\hbox{\LARGE$\cdot$}}}
                   {\vcenter{\hbox{\LARGE$\cdot$}}}
                   {\vcenter{\hbox{\normalsize$\cdot$}}}
                   {\vcenter{\hbox{\small$\cdot$}}}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
d\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\LARGE $\cdot$}b ~  d\parbox[c][0pt][c]{0.5em}{\LARGE$\cdot$}b ~ d$\vcenter{\hbox{\LARGE$\cdot$}}$b ~ d$\vcenter{\hbox{\scalefont{1.75}$\cdot$}}$b ~ d$\vcenter{\hbox{\relsize{+2.5}$\cdot$}}$b ~ d$\vcenter{\hbox{$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\cdot}}}}$}}$b
\begin{align*}
    d\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\LARGE $\cdot$}b\\
    d\parbox[c][0pt][c]{0.5em}{\LARGE$\cdot$}b\\
    d\vcenter{\hbox{\LARGE$\cdot$}}b\\
    d\vcenter{\hbox{\scalefont{1.75}$\cdot$}}b\\
    d\vcenter{\hbox{\relsize{+2.5}$\cdot$}}b\\
    d\vcenter{\hbox{$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\cdot}}}}$}}b
\end{align*}
d $\dotp$ b
\begin{align*}
    d \dotp b\\
    a_{d \dotp b}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Only the `\dotp` solution is robust. The others require manual intervention for super- and subscripts for example. You probably do want to insert some negative kerning left and right of the `\dotp`.

For the record, Hosein's answer to use `\boldsymbol{\cdot}` is also what the `physics` package uses. It also works in dvi. Still, I find that dot too small.

Comment: DVI viewers may not obey PostScript specials, so what you see is not necessarily a faithful representation of the output you'll get after translation into PostScript or PDF. Have you ever tried to look at a Ti*k*Z picture in a DVI viewer?

Comment: The screenshot was taken from Evince 3.34.1 (a.k.a. Document Viewer). If I convert the dvi to pdf with dvipdfm, then the dot product is displayed correctly in the new pdf file. So, should I assume this is an issue of Evince not obeying to the Postscript specials?

Comment: Yes, that's it: Evince just uses `xdvi` internally when asked to preview a DVI file.

Comment: My question then is: can I use Heiko's solution safely when submitting a tex article to a scientific journal? Knowing the journal eventually outputs a pdf (at least for the online version).

Comment: Would you submit the DVI file?

Comment: No, I have to submit the built files (tex and images). They post a pdf online, so that should go fine then, and the online version is most important. I guess my question is: does it make sense to use a dvi for printing? If not, the printed version should also go fine.

Comment: This question comes down to "Is `\scalebox` reliable?" It *is* an idiosyncratic add-on. However, `\scalebox` isn't needed! It is possible to specify the font size scaled (and there are probably several questions/answers on that topic already).

Comment: I tried several solutions with the packages relsize and scalefnt. The difficulty is to get the \bullet vertically centered and to scale a math font properly. Anyway, a hint to a few commands or packages would be useful.