# Smaller \bullet for homological grading

Tags: scaling, bullets

When writing (co)homological grading, the command `\bullet` yields a bullet that is too big for my taste, see the example below. Therefore, I usually define a command `\smallbullet` as below. However, my construction should probably be made more robust using `\mathpalette`, using ideas similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235118/making-a-thicker-cdot-for-dot-product-that-is-thinner-than-bullet) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389238/is-there-a-black-dot-symbol-that-i-can-use). However, if you apply the constructions from these other solutions, you get a bullet with the wrong vertical position. What would be the best (and most robust) way to correct this in my case?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\smallbullet{%
    \raisebox{-0.25ex}{\scalebox{1.2}{$\cdot$}}%
}

\begin{document}

$ H^{\bullet} $

$ H^{\smallbullet} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd scale down a `\bullet`, because `\cdot` has quite wide sidebearings. Here the scale factor is 0.5, adjust to suit.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\smallbullet}{} % for safety
\DeclareRobustCommand\smallbullet{%
  \mathord{\mathpalette\smallbullet@{0.5}}%
}
\newcommand{\smallbullet@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$ H^{\bullet} $

$ H^{\smallbullet} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One thing I’ve never quite understood is: Why are people using `%` at the end of lines *for math mode-only commands*? I understand it for text mode commands where these spaces would actually matter, but not math mode commands.

Comment: Uniformity, I'd say

Comment: I tried rewriting your code in `expl3`, but I am unsure if there are ways to do things better with the new standards? I have posted it as a separate answer. Any comments are welcome. `:-)`

Comment: @Gaussler As there aren't yet interfaces to `\mathpalette` or `\vcenter`, I'm not sure I'd go for `expl3` in this case.

Comment: But if you had to (and I have to, as I intend to use it in an `expl3` package), would you do it this way?

Comment: @Gaussler Yes, that's essentially what you should do. Maybe define an own wrapper for `\hbox_set:Nn`, say `\gaussler_math_hbox_set:Nnn`, where the first argument is the box register, the second argument a style selection and the third the material to set, so you can add to it `\mathsurround=0pt` without need to do it explicitly in the macro. Note that `\__gaussler_bullet_auxiliary:Nn` should be protected as well.

Comment: But you did not protect your command `\smallbullet@`? Anyway, why does it matter if it is used inside a robust command anyway?

Comment: @Gaussler Uniformity.

Comment: Seems you like uniforms a lot. `;-)`

Answer (score 4):

Using for the small`\bullet` the nice *macro* of Steven B. Segletes in this question, [Is there a black 'dot' symbol that I can use?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389238/is-there-a-black-dot-symbol-that-i-can-use)

```
\newcommand\sbullet[1][.5]{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \scalebox{#1}{$\SavedStyle\bullet$}}}}}%
}
```

that I have a bit adapted, I suggest to use `\strut` to have a better positioning of the bullet as superscript. Here there is a possibile MWE that shows two different size of the bullets in addendum to the classical `\bullet`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,scalerel}
\newcommand\sbullet[1][.5]{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \scalebox{#1}{$\SavedStyle\bullet$}}}}}%
}
\newcommand\smbullet[1][.8]{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \scalebox{#1}{$\SavedStyle\bullet$}}}}}%
}
\begin{document}
$H\strut^{\bullet}, H\strut^{\sbullet}, H\strut^{\smbullet}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Using your macro you will have the same and correct height for the `\smallbullet` or `\bullet`:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \newcommand\smallbullet{%
    \raisebox{-0.25ex}{\scalebox{1.2}{$\cdot$}}%
}

    \begin{document}
    $P\strut^{\bullet}, H\strut^{\smallbullet}$
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I decided to rewrite egreg’s excellent answer in `expl3`. However, as many TeX concepts (such as `\vcenter` and `\mathpalette`) seem to not yet have `expl3` analogues, I was forced to mix up old and new standards. I was hoping egreg would comment and tell me if there is something that could be improved?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn\gaussler_set_mathsurround_to_zero:
{
     % This is equivalent to "\m@th"
    \dim_set:Nn \mathsurround { 0pt }
}

\cs_set_protected:Npn\gaussler_bullet:
{
    \mathord{\mathpalette\__gaussler_bullet_auxiliary:Nn{0.5}}
}

\box_new:N \l__gaussler_bullet_box

\cs_set_protected:Npn\__gaussler_bullet_auxiliary:Nn#1#2
{
    \hbox_set:Nn \l__gaussler_bullet_box { $\gaussler_set_mathsurround_to_zero: #1 \bullet$ }
    \box_scale:Nnn \l__gaussler_bullet_box { #2 } { #2 }
    \vcenter{ \hbox:n { \box_use_drop:N \l__gaussler_bullet_box } }
}

\cs_set_eq:NN\smallbullet \gaussler_bullet:

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$ H^{\bullet} $

$ H^{\smallbullet} $

\end{document}
```