# How can I increase the size of the \bullet a little bit?

Tags: bullets

I have this macro:

```
\def\hstress#1{\leavevmode\vbox{\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\cr$\bullet$\cr\bf#1\cr}}}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to increase the size of `\bullet`` just a little.
Thank you.

Comment: Why not use `\scalebox{1.3}{$\bullet$}`

Comment: I had no idea `scalebox` exists as I'm new to LaTeX. Do I need to import a separate package in order to use it?

Comment: load `graphicx`.

Comment: Thank you. It works.

Comment: Another solution would be to use `\mathlarger{\bullet}`, from the `relsize` package.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564408/smaller-bullet-for-homological-grading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
  \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx}

   \begin{document}

   {Tiny bullet: \tiny \textbullet}
     
   {Normally sized bullet: \textbullet}
      
   {Large bullets: \Large \textbullet}

   {Custom size bullet x1.5: \scalebox{1.5}{$\bullet$}}
     
   {Custom size bullet x1.5: \scalebox{2.0}{$\bullet$}}
   \end{document}
```