# dot on a subscript mathmode

Tags: equations, formatting, symbols, indexing, subscripts

I am suppressing some of my subindexes in some equations, and I am using a dot in order to signal which dimension is gone. Up to now, I have been using a `\bullet` symbol as a *dot*. Is this the **"correct"** what of doing it, or is there another symbol I am unaware of?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\beta_{kn} &\sim \left(1\times 1\right) \\
\boldsymbol{\beta}_{k\bullet} &= \left(\beta_{k1},\dots,\beta_{kN}\right) \sim \left(N\times 1\right) \\
\boldsymbol{\beta}_{\bullet n} &= \left(\beta_{1n},\dots,\beta_{Kn}\right) \sim \left(1\times K\right)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\textperiodcentered,` which might require `\usepackage{textcomp}`

Comment: @MadyYuvi that might end too small and easily overlooked

Comment: I'd probably use `{\cdot}` but no right and wrong, just whatever you prefer

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564408/smaller-bullet-for-homological-grading

Answer (score 1):

I like use `_` instead of dot.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\beta_{kn}                & \sim \left(1\times 1\right)                                            \\
\boldsymbol{\beta}_{k\_}  & = \left(\beta_{k1},\dots,\beta_{kN}\right) \sim \left(N\times 1\right) \\
\boldsymbol{\beta}_{\_ n} & = \left(\beta_{1n},\dots,\beta_{Kn}\right) \sim \left(1\times K\right)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this the real answer for the `OP`'s question?

Comment: @MadyYuvi I know what OP wants is a dot. It will be helpful if OP thinks the `_` is better. If still like dot, then ignore my answer.