# How do I properly define a small square math symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, fontsize, scaling

I would like to create a math symbol using a command `\smallsquare`, which would look like this:

I know that there is `\sqbullet` from the mathabx package, or `\filledsquare` from the mnsymbol package, but I would like to avoid using those (e.g. because there are conflicts with other packages...).

Using the [suggestions from this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7462/how-to-make-math-symbols-bigger?noredirect=1&lq=1), here is what I tried (and gave me the above result) :

```
\newcommand{\smallsquare}{     
     \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{0.45}{$\;\mathbin{ \blacksquare }\;$}}}    
}
```

(using the `graphicx` package).
But I feel like I am not defined things properly : typically, I added a space `\;` because I didn't know how to get correct spacing – despite trying to use `\mathbin`.
I tried other ideas (e.g. `\mbox{\tiny$\blacksquare$}` or `\text{\smaller[100]$\blacksquare$}`) but did not get better results.

Henceforth, do you have any suggestions to improve my `\smallsquare` symbol? I would be happy to learn some new tricks, nice commands, interesting typographic features, etc.

Comment: There’s `\smblksquare` (▪) in several packages, including `unicode-math`, `stix` and `stix2`. I’d recommend using `unicode-math` in LuaTeX when you can, and legacy packages in  PDFTeX when you have to.

Comment: `\mathbin{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}` using whatever lengths you want?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : thanks, it is an interesting idea. This only problem is that this is not centered vertically. So I came up with `F   \vcenter{ \hbox{ \rule{1mm}{1mm} } }  H`, which seems to be quite good to me (even without the `mathbin`...).

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235118/making-a-thicker-cdot-for-dot-product-that-is-thinner-than-bullet, which gives another way (my first attempt was not far from this) : `\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{0.45}{$\blacksquare$}}}}`

Comment: you can use vcenter or (more efficiently) use the optional depth argument of `\rule`  you want `\mathbin` to get the spacing  for f ▪ g not f▪g

Answer (score 1):

You can use the non-conflicting glyphs from `mathabx` without  loading the package. You just have to add this code to your preamble:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{%
 <-6> mathb5
 <6-7> mathb6
 <7-8> mathb7
 <8-9> mathb8
 <9-10> mathb9
 <10-12> mathb10
 <12-> mathb12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqbullet}{\mathbin}{mathb}{"0D}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, thanks. Somehow this symbol is still too big, to my taste. So maybe [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578083/how-do-i-properly-define-a-small-square-math-symbol/578086#comment1454999_578083) is more interesting for me.

Comment: @Watson: be aware the  posted screenshot   is zoomed by 300 %.