# Small hollow circle in math, smaller than \circ

Tags: math-mode, markdown

I am writing a markdown document and I want to reproduce the following formula:

[image]

I'm trying to do it with the following:

```
$$
\underbrace{X_t}_\text{Population at time $t$} =
\underbrace{\alpha \circ X_{t-1}}_\text{Survivors from time $t-1$} +
\underbrace{\epsilon_t}_\text{Immigration} 
$$
```

But I get this:

[image]

In which the circle operator between $\alpha$ and $X_{t-1}$ is quite bigger (and thinner?) than what it needs to be. How can I solve it?

(I am going to ask another question about underbrace sizes.)

---

**Edit:** Related question: [Making a thicker \cdot for dot product (that is thinner than \bullet)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235118/making-a-thicker-cdot-for-dot-product-that-is-thinner-than-bullet)

Comment: For some reason, the inline math (`$...$`) in the question does not render correctly. Why is that happening?

Comment: Thanks, @campa! It does to a great extent (by reducing it to the desired size), but it would be better if also became thicker too, as if the shrunk circle was bolded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to insert a `tikz` circle, with width and line width that you chose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\circo}{~\raisebox{1pt}{\tikz \draw[line width=0.6pt] circle(1.1pt);}~}
\begin{document}
$$
\underbrace{X_t}_\text{Population at time $t$} =
\underbrace{\alpha \circo X_{t-1}}_\text{Survivors from time $t-1$} +
\underbrace{\epsilon_t}_\text{Immigration} 
$$

\end{document}
```

[image: bold round sign]

Comment: Thanks, this solves it :)