# Using newcommand in math environment lyx doesn't work

Tags: lyx

I need to make "wide dot" for time derivative.

I followed what is written here : [How to make a larger "\dot"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/how-to-make-a-larger-dot)

I have put

```
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand*{\dt}[1]{%
  \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .}}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\ddt}[1]{%
  \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .\hspace{-0.25ex}.}}{#1}}
```

In Latex Preamble in Lyx document settings.

However in mathmode (CTRL-M), if I write

```
\dt{x}
```

It doesn't display an $x$ with a dot above.

How to fix it ?

Comment: Why not just use the standard TeX commands `\dot x` and `\ddot x` ? (In math-mode, of course.)
`

Comment: @Andrew because the dot are very small and barely lisible over the letter